# Can't have two network interface enabled at the same time?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, route

Rocky Linux 8 X86-64 on a PC with two Ethernet interfaces, each connected to isolated switch hub, then connect to router.

```
LAN1: 192.168.1.2/24 <--> Hub1 <--> 192.168.1.1 (Router port #1)
LAN2: 192.168.2.2/24 <--> Hub2 <--> 192.168.2.1 (Router port #2) 
                           |
                           +------> Laptop (192.168.2.100/24, GW=192.168.2.1)
```

*(P.S.: I've already stripped out all the other cables so the real world environment is what exactly shown in the picture above. And I don't think there is any Loop)*

Both `LAN1` and `LAN2` have set corresponding Gateway correctly. The router have static route rule (port#1 <--> port#2) setup correctly, too. There is another Laptop connected to Hub2 and set IP to `192.168.2.100/24`, GW=`192.168.2.1`.

The problem is: **I can't connect to `192.168.1.2` from the Laptop**, unless I disable `LAN2` network interface on Rockey Linux. Even `PING` won't response.

More details:

1. If I disable `LAN2`, I'd be able to access `192.168.1.2` from the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet without any problem.
2. Just unplug the cable from Hub doesn't work. I have to completely disable the network interface with `nmcli`/`nmtui` to make `LAN1` being able to response.
3. If I continuously `PING` from the Laptop, it will stop responding the moment when I re-enable `LAN2` again.
4. All the PC, laptop and router can `PING` each other on the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet without problem, so it can’t be ARP related issue.

It seems as though the operating system is making an excessive effort to send the response packet via `LAN2` (which is not even the default gateway) instead of using the interface that originally received the packet.

The default route table looks like this:

```
Destination  Gateway   Genmask        Flag  Metric  Iface 
default      _gateway  0.0.0.0        UG    102     ens18
192.168.2.0  0.0.0.0   255.255.255.0  U     101     en1sf31
192.168.1.0  0.0.0.0   255.255.255.0  U     102     ens18
```

I've no idea what's going on.

For some reason I'd need to access `192.168.1.2` from `192.168.2.0/24` subnet while keeping both network interface alive.

Please help.

Comment: Can you check the arp table on hub2?

Comment: @K-attila- All the PC, laptop and router can ping each other on 192.168.2.0/24 subnets (hub2) without problem, so I don’t think it’s ARP related problem. The issue here is that Linux fails to bind the response socket to the network interface that originally receives request, and it happens on all ICMP, TCP and UDP. So it’s should be problem in the IP layer.

Comment: Ok, the spanning tree always suspicious for me.

Comment: So it's a dual-homed system with an asymmetric routing issue. The asymmetric routing can make packets dropped by the routing stack of rocky or of the router when they follow [RFC 3704](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2).

Comment: To at least verify the drop is not on Rocky (not to provide a solution): what's the result on rocky of: `ip route get from 192.168.2.100 iif ens18 to 192.168.1.2`? is there a route solution or does it tell `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid cross-device link`?

Comment: @A.B just left the lab. Will try next morning. Can confirm it’s not dropped by router, since I can ping 192.168.2.100 from LAN1 (when LAN2 is disabled) without any problem.

Comment: Just a stupid question: did you enabled routing in your laptop? By default Linux kernel will not "forward" packets from one interface to the other.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi no I don’t need to enable “routing” on the laptop because it’s the standalone router, to be specific, a **FortiGate 50E**, that takes care of IP forwarding between 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24 subnets. The laptop has only one network interface and only one default gateway set to 192.168.2.1, which is the port #2 of  FortiGate 50E. And what exactly did you expect me to set the routing rule on the laptop anyway ? One-Armed router ? BTW, there *was* other PCs and Internet connected to this network but I removed them all, to figure out the problem.

Comment: Investigate with `man traceroute ping`. Also, `wireshark`, see `https://wireshark.org`. In your diagram, I see no HUB1<->HUB2 connection. Which network entity is doing the "packet formatting"?

Comment: @waltinator the "Router port#1" and "Router port#2" are two ports on a FortiGate 50E router. Guess I should remake the picture with some drawing tools.

Comment: @A.B I've tested `ip route get` and it says "RTNETLINK answers: Invalid cross-device link".

Comment: @A.B SOLVED. It's caused by `rp_filter` and set it to 2 via `sysctl` solved the problem. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
```

To make this change persistent across reboots, add it to `/etc/sysctl.conf` .

**Full answer**: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031

Simply put, the packet is dropped by Rocky Linux, due to "Strict Reverse Path Forwarding filtering" recommended in RFC 3704. Disabling it or set it to loose solve the problem.

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/967863/routing-from-one-server-to-another-with-different-interfaces